# SharePoint 2010: Disconnect People Search from My Site

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I've got the 'My Site' functionality basically disabled so users can't get to that stuff from the menu under their names. The problem is we have need for a company directory, and I used the Enterprise Search Center to create a staff directory and everything in the default results links to some page or another in the '/my' built in site collection. How can I disconnect the people search entirely from the 'My Site' system?

Answer (score 0):

You can limit all the searches with a search scope to your site collection. That would trim out Personal from the results. Then set the scope on the search box or write a custom results page.